# Android Studio app not starting or crashing

Tags: java, android

i am just starting out with android and i just dont know why its not working i am pretty lost right now the whole Logcat is red.
I want the user to input text into an `editText` and than do some calculations with it and than output it to a `textView`.
i declared the variable sss in a class named global so i can acess it everywhere (public static int sss;).

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import de.niklas.unitconverter.global;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        EditText edittext=findViewById(R.id.editText);
        edittext.addTextChangedListener(Watcher);
        TextView textview=findViewById(R.id.textView);
        textview.setText(global.sss);
    }
    TextWatcher Watcher = new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            if (count>0){
                String ss=String.valueOf(s);
                global.sss=Integer.parseInt(ss);
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }
    };
}
```

those are the error messages:

> 2019-01-12 15:04:08.785 1630-6935/? E/AudioFlinger: not enough memory for >AudioTrack size=131296
>   2019-01-12 15:04:08.785 1630-6935/? E/AudioFlinger: createRecordTrack_l() >initCheck failed -12; no control block?
>   2019-01-12 15:04:08.787 2412-2690/? E/IAudioFlinger: createRecord returned error -12
>   2019-01-12 15:04:08.788 2412-2690/? E/AudioRecord: AudioFlinger could not create record track, status: -12
>   2019-01-12 15:04:08.788 2412-2690/? E/AudioRecord-JNI: Error creating AudioRecord instance: initialization check failed with status -12.
>   2019-01-12 15:04:08.789 2412-2690/? E/android.media.AudioRecord: Error code -20 when initializing native AudioRecord object.
>   2019-01-12 15:04:08.790 2412-2690/? E/ActivityThread: Failed to find provider info for com.google.android.apps.gsa.testing.ui.audio.recorded
>   2019-01-12 15:04:10.819 1729-1944/? E/installd: Failed to delete /data/app/vmdl1735704553.tmp: No such file or directory
>   2019-01-12 15:04:11.533 2726-7128/? E/native: document-store.cc:1423 Failed to update per-doc-data with usage report
>   2019-01-12 15:04:11.559 7102-7102/de.niklas.unitconverter E/s.unitconverte: Invalid ID 0x00000000.
>   2019-01-12 15:04:11.563 7102-7102/de.niklas.unitconverter E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>       Process: de.niklas.unitconverter, PID: 7102
>       java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{de.niklas.unitconverter/de.niklas.unitconverter.MainActivity}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x0
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2913)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3048)
>           at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
>           at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
>           at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1808)
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>           at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
>        Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x0
>           at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:348)
>           at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:5831)
>           at de.niklas.unitconverter.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:21)
>           at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7136)
>           at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7127)
>           at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1271)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2893)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3048) 
>           at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78) 
>           at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108) 
>           at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1808) 
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669) 
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>           at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493) 
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858) 
>   2019-01-12 15:04:11.576 1631-1631/? E/lowmemorykiller: Error writing /proc/7102/oom_score_adj; errno=22
>   2019-01-12 15:04:11.619 2726-7128/? E/native: document-store.cc:1423 Failed to update per-doc-data with usage report
>   2019-01-12 15:04:11.842 1630-1698/? E/AudioFlinger: not enough memory for AudioTrack size=131296
>   2019-01-12 15:04:11.842 1630-1698/? E/AudioFlinger: createRecordTrack_l() initCheck failed -12; no control block?
>   2019-01-12 15:04:11.844 2412-2690/? E/IAudioFlinger: createRecord returned error -12
>   2019-01-12 15:04:11.844 2412-2690/? E/AudioRecord: AudioFlinger could not create record track, status: -12
>   2019-01-12 15:04:11.844 2412-2690/? E/AudioRecord-JNI: Error creating AudioRecord instance: initialization check failed with status -12.
>   2019-01-12 15:04:11.844 2412-2690/? E/android.media.AudioRecord: Error code -20 when initializing native AudioRecord object.
>   2019-01-12 15:04:11.846 2412-2690/? E/ActivityThread: Failed to find provider info for com.google.android.apps.gsa.testing.ui.audio.recorded
>   2019-01-12 15:11:11.088 1630-1630/? E/AudioFlinger: not enough memory for AudioTrack size=131296
>   2019-01-12 15:11:11.088 1630-1630/? E/AudioFlinger: createRecordTrack_l() initCheck failed -12; no control block?
>   2019-01-12 15:11:11.090 2412-2690/? E/IAudioFlinger: createRecord returned error -12
>   2019-01-12 15:11:11.090 2412-2690/? E/AudioRecord: AudioFlinger could not create record track, status: -12
>   2019-01-12 15:11:11.090 2412-2690/? E/AudioRecord-JNI: Error creating AudioRecord instance: initialization check failed with status -12.
>   2019-01-12 15:11:11.091 2412-2690/? E/android.media.AudioRecord: Error code -20 when initializing native AudioRecord object.
>   2019-01-12 15:11:11.091 2412-2690/? E/ActivityThread: Failed to find provider info for com.google.android.apps.gsa.testing.ui.audio.recorded

Comment: this error is about an `audioTrack` , you code has not an `audioTrack`. Please give the code that takes the error

Answer (score 1):

You are attempting to populate your TextView with an integer, causing the system to think you are trying to use a resource which does not exist. You should call setText with a String.

```
textview.setText("" + global.sss);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your passing a integer value (sss) for setText method setText method only accept string values.convert integer value to string using String.valueOf(int) method
`textview.setText(String.valueOf(global.sss));`